# Php form action not working

Tags: php, web

These codes work with phpMailer. There is no reaction to butona press. why could it be? Do you have a suggestion? I ran the code on a blank project without including it in the project. I did not find any problems. I do not understand whether there is a mistake in the form. (send.php works. So send.php sends an e-mail.
)

**index.php** my home page

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/slider.php';?>
<?php include 'includes/onepage-home.php';?>
<?php include 'contact.php';?>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

**contact.php** contact form page

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="contact-forms">
        <form class="b-form b-contact-form home-contact-form" method="post" action="send.php">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input class="field-name input-lg i-field" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input class="field-email input-lg i-field" placeholder="eMail" name="email" type="text">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap">
                <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" type="text">

            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap">
                <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" type="text">

            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap">
                <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Address" name="address" type="text">

            </div>
            <div class="textarea-wrap">
                <textarea class="field-comments input-lg i-field" placeholder="Message" name="mail"></textarea>

            </div>
            <input class="button" value="Send" type="submit">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**send.php** mail send page

```
<?php 

 $mail_address  = "mailsend@envem.com";
 $mail_pass = "*****";
 $send_address  = "walidawad@envem.com";
 $domain_address    = "envem.com";

 require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer();

 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->Host = "smtp.".$domain_address;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
 $mail->Port = 465;
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->Username = $mail_address;
 $mail->Password = $mail_pass;

 $mail->setFrom('senaidbacinovic@gmail.com', 'Senaid Bacinovic');
 $mail->addAddress($send_address);
 $mail->name = $_POST["name"];
 $mail->email = $_POST["email"];
 $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
 $mail->phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $mail->address = $_POST["address"];
 $mail->mail = $_POST["mail"];
 $mail->Body = 


 $_POST["name"]."\n".$_POST["email"]."\n".$_POST["subject"]."\n".$_POST["phone"]."\n".$_POST["address"]."\n".$_POST["mail"];


if(!$mail->send()){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Bir hata olustu.");</script> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php" />';

exit;

}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mesaj Basariyla Gönderildi.");


</script> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php" />';

 ?>
```

Comment: Your code contains SMTP credentials. / What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Can you provide the folders hirarchy please?  And please be more specific about your problem

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Phpmailer folder and send.php file in the source file (In the same place as the index file.). onepage-home.php in the includes file.

Comment: There is no answer on the button. at least he does not even make a mistake.

Comment: I just started writing. it works very well. Thank you very much. @RiggsFolly

Comment: There is no answer on the button. at least he does not even make a mistake. @NieDzejkob

Answer (score 0):

**`contact.php`** contact form page. I removed the "`b-form b-contact-form`" classes found on the `contact.php` page and not used on the `style.css` page.

**new contact.php:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
<div class="contact-forms">
<form class="home-contact-form" method="post" action="send.php">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="input-wrap">
             <input class="field-name input-lg i-field" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="input-wrap">
            <input class="field-email input-lg i-field" placeholder="eMail" name="email" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="input-wrap">
       <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" type="text">

   </div>
   <div class="input-wrap">
     <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" type="text">
   </div>
  <div class="input-wrap">
     <input class="field-subject input-lg i-field" placeholder="Address" name="address" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="textarea-wrap">
     <textarea class="field-comments input-lg i-field" placeholder="Message" name="mail"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="button" value="Send" type="submit">

 </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

*There is a response when I click on the submit button.*